# iOS- Chatto framework chat deletion

Tags: ios, swift

I have been using the `Chatto` framework for working in a chat application. Everything works fine. Now I want to delete a chat message from `DataSource` which is `SlidingDataSource` class. The indexing of the array is being handled with some properties like `windowOffset` `itemsOffset` `windowCount` along with the array's count. If anyone has used delete operation in `Chatto`, Please explain the properties or provide a simple function to delete will be helpful. 
Thank you. I am attaching the data source code here..

```
import Foundation
import Chatto

public enum InsertPosition {
    case top
    case bottom
}

public class SlidingDataSource<Element> {

    private var pageSize: Int
    private var windowOffset: Int
    private var windowCount: Int
    private var itemGenerator: (() -> Element)?
    private var items = [Element]()
    private var itemsOffset: Int
    public var itemsInWindow: [Element] {
        let offset = self.windowOffset - self.itemsOffset
        return Array(items[offset..<offset+self.windowCount])
    }

    public init(count: Int, pageSize: Int, itemGenerator: (() -> Element)?) {
        self.windowOffset = count
        self.itemsOffset = count
        self.windowCount = 0
        self.pageSize = pageSize
        self.itemGenerator = itemGenerator
        self.generateItems(min(pageSize, count), position: .top)
    }

    public convenience init(items: [Element], pageSize: Int) {
        var iterator = items.makeIterator()
        self.init(count: items.count, pageSize: pageSize) { iterator.next()! }
    }

    private func generateItems(_ count: Int, position: InsertPosition) {
        // swiftlint:disable:next empty_count
        guard count > 0 else { return }
        guard let itemGenerator = self.itemGenerator else {
            fatalError("Can't create messages without a generator")
        }
        for _ in 0..<count {
            self.insertItem(itemGenerator(), position: .top)
        }
    }

    public func insertItem(_ item: Element, position: InsertPosition) {
        if position == .top {
            self.items.insert(item, at: 0)
            let shouldExpandWindow = self.itemsOffset == self.windowOffset
            self.itemsOffset -= 1
            if shouldExpandWindow {
                self.windowOffset -= 1
                self.windowCount += 1
            }
        } else {
            let shouldExpandWindow = self.itemsOffset + self.items.count == self.windowOffset + self.windowCount
            if shouldExpandWindow {
                self.windowCount += 1
            }
            self.items.append(item)
        }
    }

    public func hasPrevious() -> Bool {
        return self.windowOffset > 0
    }

    public func hasMore() -> Bool {
        return self.windowOffset + self.windowCount < self.itemsOffset + self.items.count
    }

    public func loadPrevious() {
        let previousWindowOffset = self.windowOffset
        let previousWindowCount = self.windowCount
        let nextWindowOffset = max(0, self.windowOffset - self.pageSize)
        let messagesNeeded = self.itemsOffset - nextWindowOffset
        if messagesNeeded > 0 {
            self.generateItems(messagesNeeded, position: .top)
        }
        let newItemsCount = previousWindowOffset - nextWindowOffset
        self.windowOffset = nextWindowOffset
        self.windowCount = previousWindowCount + newItemsCount
    }

    public func loadNext() {
        guard !self.items.isEmpty else { return }
        let itemCountAfterWindow = self.itemsOffset + self.items.count - self.windowOffset - self.windowCount
        self.windowCount += min(self.pageSize, itemCountAfterWindow)
    }

    @discardableResult
    public func adjustWindow(focusPosition: Double, maxWindowSize: Int) -> Bool {
        assert(0 <= focusPosition && focusPosition <= 1, "")
        guard 0 <= focusPosition && focusPosition <= 1 else {
            assert(false, "focus should be in the [0, 1] interval")
            return false
        }
        let sizeDiff = self.windowCount - maxWindowSize
        guard sizeDiff > 0 else { return false }
        self.windowOffset +=  Int(focusPosition * Double(sizeDiff))
        self.windowCount = maxWindowSize
        return true
    }

    @discardableResult
    func replaceItem(withNewItem item: Element, where predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        guard let index = self.items.firstIndex(where: predicate) else { return false }
        self.items[index] = item
        return true
    }
    func contains(item: Element, where predicate: (Element) -> Bool ) -> Bool {
        guard let _ = self.items.firstIndex(where: predicate) else { return false }
        return true
    }
    //FIXME: Add delete method here, don't know the use off itemOffset, windowOffset, windowCount

    //    func delete(item: Element, where predicate: (Element) -> Bool ) {
    //        self.items.removeAll(where: predicate)
    //    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have raised a question in their Github repo. Here is the solution they answered.

```
when delete or add a new element in data source you need to -1 or +1 to offset. If offset is 0 - do nothing.
```

[Originial answer link](https://github.com/badoo/Chatto/issues/633)